# php call constant with using a variable

Tags: php, variables, post, constants

```
//include.php
    define('OPTION_0', 'Essence of population');
    define('OPTION_1', 'Passport request/extend');
    define('OPTION_2', 'Request logging concession');

//form.php
    <select name="sort">
        <option value="0"><?php echo(O_0) ?></option>
        <option value="1"><?php echo(O_1) ?></option>
        <option value="2"><?php echo(O_2 ?></option>
    </select>


//show.php
    extract($_POST);                    //The variable $sort has the value 1,2 or 3
    echo("This is your choice");
    echo(OPTION_ . $sort);              //I want to use de constant e.g. OPTION_2
```

I want to echo the value of the matching constant.
So when I select the second value in form.php it gives $sort the value of 1
now I want to use the constants OPTION_1.

Can someone help me?

Comment: sort of voids the purpose of constants

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use [constant()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function:

```
echo constant('OPTION_' . $sort);
```

> constant() is useful if you need to retrieve the value of a constant, but do not know its name. I.e. it is stored in a variable or returned by a function.